# How to delete a large number of command buttons in excel

Tags: excel, button

I have a macro that I have designed to retrieve information from the internet and then to process that information into formats I want. My first worksheet in the workbook functions as my command page and all of the subsequent worksheets are populated based on what I tell the command page I want.

I have assigned control buttons on the command page to all of the various functions I want the macro to execute on the data retrieved from the web so I can select which functions I want applied. However, I believe that somewhere along the way I told my code to make copies of 1 certain command button.

There are now over 7000 command buttons for one function. Thank fully they are all stacked on one another so it isn't obvious, however it is starting to slow my excel down.

Is there any way to manage all of you buttons and then to select the ones you wish to delete?

Maybe a macro that deletes all duplicate command button names would do the trick? Before I tried this method, I wanted to see if there was an easier fix to my problem.

Comment: Yikes.  7000 command buttons for one function?  Why did that need to happen?  Perhaps you should take a step back after this is solved and figure out how to make them dynamic instead of making a new one for every purpose.  What are those buttons doing that there needs to be so many?

Comment: peege, I accidentally placed the command button in a cell that populates down to cell 5000. I think that might be where I went wrong. Im obviously moving the command button now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work for you:

1. <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+Click on the button to select it
2. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd> to have it select all of them
3. Then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+Click the button to de-select the top-most button
4. Press the Del key to delete all selected objects.